# Azure Functions - Monitor - can I get the old view back?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In a Azure Functions the Monitor view in the Azure Portal has changed to show "Configure Application Insights...". How can I get the old simple view back?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2nd Update**

2.x runtime doesn't send logs(provided by ILogger) to the table consumed by `Azure WebJobs Dashboard` anymore. Hence we should no longer use the old view for v2 functions. Use Application Insights or the file logs mnetioned in the previous update.

---

**Update after v2 GA**

For new created functions, `Azure WebJobs Dashboard` is gone as well due to default settings. We need to delete `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`(if there is) and add `AzureWebJobsDashboard` in [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) to get old monitor back.

Azure doesn't cut this old feature for now, but as @nertim mentioned, recommended [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview) does offer richer monitoring and easy query experience.

If expecting no log analysis, disable Application Insights when creating Function app, we can still see logs stream in portal(`Logs` under function panel or the `Log streaming` in Platform features). For file logs, turn to kudu(`https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\<functoinName>`.

---

**Original Answer**

Shortly speaking, classic monitor view for v2 has gone. More details, see @nertim's reply.

Workaround is to visit `Azure WebJobs Dashboard`, which has similar content like monitor view. `https://{yourfunctionappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions`.

Answer (score 1):

Azure functions are transitioning all logging to Application Insights. For V2 and Linux based functions, the preference is that the logs always be setup up using Application Insights. All new function apps also have Application Insights enabled by default.

One can access the logs by going to the Webjobs dashboard, but Application Insights would provide similar logs, along with the ability to query for more details.

Comment: Yeah, but Application Insights costs money.

Comment: Came here looking for alternatives - my bill shows that App Insights costs 2 USD/day, while storage costs 0.07 USD/day and Azure Functions 0.03 USD/day. Every Azure Function invokation logs one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

App Insights (aka Azure Monitor APM) includes 5GB/month of free ingestion and then 2.30/GB pay as you go. Details are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/.

If you are getting charged 2USD/day you already used up the free 5GB for that month ($11.50 value) and are sending about another GB over. You can see what's causing your 6GB ingestion by looking at the APM's Cost and Usage blade (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing) or examine the raw data in the APM Logs.