# How to disable Application Insights in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Since recently, Azure Functions began forcing users to use Application Insights to capture invocation logs, instead of using the previous simple system that shows 20 most recent invocations.

My old Function Apps that didn't use Application Insights still work fine and show the logs properly.

For new Function Apps, how do I disable Application Insights and see the invocation logs without it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The original answer only works for v1 functions, 2.x runtime doesn't send logs(provided by ILogger) to the table consumed by Azure WebJobs Dashboard anymore.

Without Application Insights, we could only turn to kudu(`https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\<functoinName>` for persisted logs.

---

**Origin**

Go to Application settings on Azure portal

1. Delete `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`(if there is)
2. Add `AzureWebJobsDashboard` with one Storage Connection String.

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I found your other more detailed answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389601/azure-functions-monitor-can-i-get-the-old-view-back/50393129

Comment: @K48 Great, the first time I posted that old answer, `AzureWebJobsDashboard` didn't work so I offered the workaround. After v2 was GA, I found this setting is valid again. Since you just want it back, I cut other recommendation info already shown in portal.